# Arduino - Passing long String to a Library

Tags: string, arduino

I am trying to write my first big Arduino Library, in this case to control the ESP8266.

I would like to pass as parameter the WEBSITE address to a method that will do the GET request so I need to send two *long Strings*:

- (1) **Fix part of the website url**
- (2) json with the data to add to
  the request

1) The fix part is this:

```
  #define WEBPAGE   "/mywebsiteURLfolder/post.php?json={"
```

So I call my library method:

```
  myESPinstanceSOFT.Send_OnlineService(1, HOST, WEBSITE, 9);
```

And my library should receive it and use to create a final String that will be used to send it via Serial to the ESP8266:

```
bool ESP8266Class::Send_OnlineService(byte type, String HOST, String WEBPAGE, int Node_ID){

String request = "GET ";
      request += WEBPAGE;
      request += "Node_ID:";  

etc etc
```

Given that WEBSITE is a fix string. How can I save it in flash and just point to it when constructing the **request** string?

Thank you very much

Comment: You want to save it so that you can modify it without flashing the Arduino again? then use the EEPROM. If, on the other side, you want to embed it into the arduino, a `#define` saves it in the program memory (I don't remember if it is eeprom or flash, I suppose flash).

Comment: Or better, a `#define` does not save it anywhere. The call `myESPinstanceSOFT.Send_OnlineService(1, HOST, WEBSITE, 9);` saves it in the flash memory, so probably it's better to save it as a `static const String`